# Algolia PHP SDK Hosts unreachable

Tags: php, algolia

I am using PHP SDK(v1.8) for Algolia Search.

Having difficulty connecting to Algolia server, when calling

```
$client = new \AlgoliaSearch\Client("appId", "secret key");
$index = $client->initIndex('demo');        
$index->getSettings();
```

It throws following exceptions:

> >
>   AlgoliaSearch\AlgoliaException: Hosts unreachable: Resolving timed out after 2000 milliseconds,Resolving timed out after 2000 milliseconds,Resolving timed out after 4000 milliseconds,Resolving timed out after 4000 milliseconds,Resolving timed out after 4000 milliseconds

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that my server is having slow connection to Algolia Server.

Solved it by increasing the timeout:

```
$client->setConnectTimeout(10);
```